# Проблемы c FTP C#

Tags: c#, сервер, ftp

Вот код

```
        FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://xxx.xxx.xx//Versions/" + (isStable ? "S1.noext" : "T1.noext"));
        ftp.Proxy = null;
        ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("login", "password");
        ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.Rename;
        ftp.RenameTo = "Test.noext";
        WebResponse disp = ftp.GetResponse();
        disp.Close();
```

Если первый раз его запустить на одном файле, то файл успешно переименуется, а если запустить второй раз на другом файле в той же директории, то в GetResponse выскочит ошибка:

> Удаленный сервер возвратил ошибку: (550) Файл недоступен (например, не найден или к нему нет доступа)

Пробовал по разному задавать URI (ftp://xxx.xxx.xx/asd/ и ftp://xxx:xxx@xxx.xxx.xx/asd/), ничего не получалось, одно и то же. Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А вы уверены, что на второй итерации не выполняете метод с тем же самым `ftp.RenameTo = "Test.noext";`, что и в первый раз?

`RenameTo` не умеет заменять файл, т.е. если на сервере уже есть файл с именем, указанным в `RenameTo`, то будет ошибка.

Чтобы этой ситуации избежать, сначала удалите существующий файл отдельным запросом (`ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile`)

Comment: Здравствуйте, может вы сможете подсказать по моей похожей проблеме: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/795261/c-ftp-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8

Comment: @Anonymous Больше, чем вам VladD насоветовал, я не скажу.